# Cross reference equation in RMarkdown knitting to docx (papaja)

Tags: r-markdown, pandoc, papaja

I am trying to get equation numbers when knitting my .Rmd to .docx but I haven't found a way to get this or the labels to cross reference them to work. I tried this:

```
    $$
    P(L|C_L, C_R) = \frac {10^{\sum_{n=1}^ {4} (w_{c_{L,i}} - w_{c_{R,i}})}} {1+10^{\sum_{n=1}^ {4} (w_{c_{L,i}} - w_{c_{R,i}})}}
    $$\label(#eq:left)

The probability for the left side winning can be calculated using \@ref(eq:left)
```

Which returns this:

[image]

Referencing correctly to the equation but the label for it doesn't show (having a (1) on the left or right of the equation) and instead, it prints out the text in the code.

Does anyone know what am I writing wrong here or if this is even possible to do for .docx files?

Thanks for your help

Comment: This does not only seem to happen when knitting to .docx. Knitting to pdf_document I encounter the exact same problem, with the exact same output. Maybe you want to post an issue to the [rmarkdown github](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`papaja` extends `bookdown`, so the general approach you are trying is correct, but the syntax is a little off. Try the following:

```
\begin{equation}
P(L|C_L, C_R) = \frac {10^{\sum_{n=1}^ {4} (w_{c_{L,i}} - w_{c_{R,i}})}} {1+10^{\sum_{n=1}^ {4} (w_{c_{L,i}} - w_{c_{R,i}})}} 
(\#eq:left)
\end{equation}

The probability for the left side winning can be calculated using \@ref(eq:left)
```

Note that equation references are not well supported in Word (i.e., `apa6_docx()`). See the [here](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/markdown-extensions-by-bookdown.html#equations) for details.

Answer (score 0):

The within-document cross-referencing seems only to work with Bookdown output formats - i.e. word_document2 see here: https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/cross-ref.html

You could do use the pdf_document output and use the generic LaTeX reference for equations:

```
   \begin{equation} \label{eq:left}
        P(L|C_L, C_R) = \frac {10^{\sum_{n=1}^ {4} (w_{c_{L,i}} - w_{c_{R,i}})}} 
        {1+10^{\sum_{n=1}^ {4} (w_{c_{L,i}} - w_{c_{R,i}})}}
    \end{equation}
```

with the following to put in the reference:

```
The probability for the left side winning can be calculated using
equation \ref{eq:left}.
```

The result will look like this (depending on the number of equations and sections):

> The probability for the left side winning can be calculated using
> equation 1

Comment: I believe that should be ```\label{eq:left}```.